# jQuery: How to differ multiple same buttons and pass parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, thymeleaf

I try to move this working solution to jQuery.

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="l : ${lst}">
        <td>
            <input type="button" th:onclick="foo ([[${l}]])"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

....

function foo (x)
{
}
```

How can I do this the jQuery way? Is it a good idea to do so?

I tried this but I do not know how to get the parameter ${l} into the function also how to differ the differnt buttons.

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="l : ${lst}">
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="mybutton"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

...

$("#mybutton").click (function ()
{
});
```

Comment: Where are your `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags?

Comment: It's **invalid** to have duplicate IDs in your document. `id="mybutton"`. You forEach creating some rows, but they all will contain a button with such an ID. Use classes `class="mybutton"` and you're good to go.

Comment: After fixing the afore mentioned, use: `$("table").on("click", ".mybutton", function() {  });` - Although I'm not sure what thymeleaf syntax for `l:` is... You might want do explain

Comment: What does the `lst` array look like? Is it a list of string, integer, or object?

Comment: List of Strings is lst. Simple parameter that I pass in my working sample but with JavaScript. Try to go a pure jQuery way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your HTML to look like:

```html
<table>
  <tr th:each="l : ${lst}">
    <td>
      <input class="mybutton" type="button" value="${l}">
      <!-- Fix the above's ${l} to be the desired output value -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then in jQuery use:

```js
function foo () {
  // Do something 
  console.log(this.value); // whatever is returned by `${l}`
};

$("table").on("click", ".mybutton", foo);
```

If you need some other text for the button other than `${l}`, use a HTMLButtonElement:

```html
<table>
  <tr th:each="l : ${lst}">
    <td>
      <button class="mybutton" type="button" value="${l}">Click me!</button>
      <!-- Fix the above's ${l} to be the desired output value -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can have another text for the button than ${l}?